# Changing what the ends of whiskers represent in matplotlib's boxplot function

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I understand that the ends of whiskers in matplotlib's box plot function extend to max value below 75% + 1.5 IQR and minimum value above 25% - 1.5 IQR.  I would like to change it to represent max and minimum values of the data or the 5th and 95th quartile of the data. Is is possible to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the whiskers to appear at the min and max of the data, set the `whis` parameter to an arbitrarily large number. In other words: `boxplots = ax.boxplot(myData, whis=np.inf)`.

The `whis` kwarg is a scaling factor of the interquartile range. Whiskers are drawn to the outermost data points within `whis * IQR` away from the quartiles.

#### Now that v1.4 is out:

In matplotlib v1.4, you can say: `boxplots = ax.boxplot(myData, whis=[5, 95])` to set the whiskers at the 5th and 95th percentiles. Similarly, you'll be able to say `boxplots = ax.boxplot(myData, whis=[0, 100])` to set the whiskers at the min and max.

Note: you could probably modify the artists contained in the `boxplots` dictionary returned by the [`ax.boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html) method, but that seems like a huge hassle

Answer (score 1):

Set the boxplot option whisk=0 to hide the inbuilt whiskers. Then create the custom whiskers that show data from 5% to 95%.

```
#create markings that represent the ends of whiskers
low=data.quantile(0.05) 
high=data.quantile(0.95)
plt.scatter(range(1,len(low)+1),low,marker='_')
plt.scatter(range(1,len(low)+1),high,marker='_')
#connects low and high markers with a line
plt.vlines(range(1,len(low)+1),low,high)
```

That should create vertical lines with whisker markings behind the boxes at 5% at 95%.