# Pandas / Matplotlib : boxplot with multiple whisker marks for different percentiles?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I am using Pandas and Matplotlib to plot [boxplots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot). I understand that the whisker endpoints typically represent outlier values, such `max`/`min`, `Q3 + 1.5 IQR` / `Q1 - 1.5 IQR`, etc. I know that you can set what the endpoints represent with the `boxplot()` parameter `whis` in the function call.

What I want is to show **multiple** indicators of outliers, such as multiple percentiles. So the boxplot could show max, 99th, 90th, ... 10th, 1st, min, as shown below.

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

I already found these Stackoverflow questions but could not find an answer:

[Boxplots in matplotlib: Markers and outliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725927/boxplots-in-matplotlib-markers-and-outliers/23324730#23324730)

[Changing what the ends of whiskers represent in matplotlib's boxplot function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997897/changing-what-the-ends-of-whiskers-represent-in-matplotlibs-boxplot-function)

Comment: I see two options 1) add them yourself with raw matplotlib commands, 2) make multiple calls to `boxplot`, plotting several identical boxes with different whiskers on top of each other. There's no official way to do it through a single call to the `boxplot` function. You might get lucky by specifying multiple whisker lengths in the `bxp` function https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3631